# Adding subcategory to existing category Woocommerce WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

is there any way to give a category that already exists an sub-category in Woocommerce in WordPress using php?

Like.. For example I have the Category "Fruit" and I want to create a sub-category called "Peach". How can I do that with php?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `wp_insert_term()` function to do this, and taxonomy `product_cat`

description and slug are optional

```
function wpse_insert_term()
{
wp_insert_term(
  'Peach',
  'product_cat', // the taxonomy
  array(
    'description'=> 'Child Cat Description',
    'slug' => 'peach',
    'parent' => 99, // term ID of parent "Fruit" category
  )
    );
}
add_action('init', 'wpse_insert_term');
```

Comment: I know that. But I need the PHP- way because I'm adding a lot of categories at once...

Comment: [`wp_insert_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term) is correct, but `parent` is numerical according to the docs.